# How to obtain a product-to-sum identity for the sinc function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

We know that
$$\text{sinc}(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$$
and for some truncated $k$ we can write the following product-to-sum identity:
$$\prod _{n=1}^k \cos \left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\sum _{n=1}^{2^{k-1}} \cos \left(\frac{n-1/2}{2^{k-1}} x\right).$$
It there a product-to-sum identity for this equation:
$$\text{sinc}(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2}\right)$$
at some truncated value of $k$? Any ideas?

Comment: If you replace your latter infinite product by a corresponding finite partial one, then you will get a polynomial (in $x^2$), which is a finite sum of monomials, with certain rather explicit coefficients. Will that be enough for you?

Comment: @ IosifPinelis: I can do it only if I know a specific value of $k$. However, I want the product-to-sum identity for an arbitrary integer $k$. Such a formula would be useful, for example, in integration involving the sinc function.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to represent the truncated infinite product in your last display as a sum: 
$$\prod_{n=1}^k\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2}\Big)
=\sum_{J\subseteq[k]}\Big(-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\Big)^{|J|}\prod_{n\in J}\frac1{n^2},  
$$
for any natural $k$.

However, since, according to your comment, you wanted a formula useful in integration involving the sinc function, it is much easier and likely better to just truncate the Maclaurin series for $\text{sinc}$:
$$
\text{sinc}(x)\approx\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(-x^2)^j}{(2j+1)!}. 
$$